# List All Databases Without Tables (Among Other DB objects)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to execute a system query in T-SQL that lists all databases on a server that don't have any tables? Moreover, it is possible to do this with common objects like list databases that don't have tables, views, and stored procedures (all at once, meaning 0 tables, 0 views, and 0 stored procs in a database, then it gets listed)

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the undocumented procedure `sp_MSforeachdb` along with the views in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.  Note that one result set is returned for each database.

```
--List of db's with no user tables.
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; SELECT DB_NAME()
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t 
    WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE''
)'

--List of db's with no stored procedures.
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; SELECT DB_NAME()
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES r
    WHERE r.ROUTINE_TYPE = ''PROCEDURE''
)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I love powershell for this sort of thing

```
import-module sqlps;
$server = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server '.';
foreach ($db in $server.Databases) {
   if ($db.Tables.Count -eq 0) {
      $db.Name
   }
}
```

I leave it as an exercise for the reader to extend this to other object types (i.e. stored procedures, views, etc).